# How to print a value of table 1 between timerange

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables as below.

Table A

```
timestamp | stats-taken
122222222 | ingested.between[2019/09/09 to 2019/09/10]
124444444 | ingested.between[2019/09/10 to 2019/09/11]
125555555 | ingested.between[2019/09/11 to 2019/09/12]
122222222 | ingested.between[2019/09/12 to 2019/09/13]
```

Table B

```
timestamp | stats | value
122222222 | abc   | 0
122222444 | abc   | 20
122225555 | abc   | 66
124444444 | abc   | 0
124445555 | abc   | 60
124447777 | abc   | 1666
```

like this there are multiple values for stats column.

Table A represents the timestamp start of stats query
Table B has the actual stats along with timestamp but no query

I tried joining these 2 tables using JOIN, but i get NULL values for rows not matching with TABLE A

Ex:

SELECT stats-taken, stats, value FROM TABLEA RIGHT JOIN TABLEB ON TABLEA.timestamp = TABLEB.timestamp;

gives

```
stats-taken                                  | stats | value
ingested.between[2019/09/09 to 2019/09/10]   | abc   | 0
NULL                                         | abc | 20
```

I need to get the query printed for all rows in TABLE B whose timestamp < timestamp of TABLE A, and when it changes, the new set of values should be printed

Comment: Seems to be correct.. Can you share your expected output?

Comment: @tcadidot0 My Expected result is that I dont want to get NULL values, rather I would like to have the row-value of previous row for all NULL values, until this is changed.

Comment: Isn't that the result you get from the query?

Comment: Nope, I am getting NULL values

Comment: In that case can you help me to run the following statements: `SHOW COLUMNS FROM TableA;` &  `SHOW COLUMNS FROM TableB;` then paste the result in here? Also the results you get - all NULL?

Comment: TABLE A will just have one entry of the query with timestamp for a day (Ex: At TIME 1 - Query 1, At Time 30 - Query 2, so on)
but TABLE B will keep sampling data with that query and loogs in TABLE B every 2 hours (say), So, TABLE B above will have multiple entries from TIME 1 to TIME 20.....

Now, Expected Result is

~~~
TIME 1 QUERY 1 STATS 1
TIME 2 QUERY 1 STATS 2
.
.
.
TIME 20 QUERY 1 STATS 20
TIME 31 QUERY 2 STATS 31
TIME 32 QUERY 2 STATS 32
.
.
.
TIME n QUERY K STATS n
~~~

Comment: Ok.. how about this, can you see this fiddle.. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9PDksvs8HfuJRkP7bXoZox/0 .. I created it exactly same as your example table and using your query to run. Click the "Run" button at top left and look at the results below, is it similar to what you get?

Comment: @tcadidot0 excellent, yes, this is what i get...but my expected results are different as mentioned above. How can we fix this.

Very kind of you to have responded back quickly

Comment: You mean you want to show just two rows? or you want it to be in order like TableB?

Comment: I want to populate the value of TableA for vlaues coming as NULL, Instead of NULL, I want to populate the value of TableA

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://imgur.com/LH3bfPB

Comment: Nope...I have posted a detailed description in duplicate question.. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57970693/mysql-varying-timestamp-as-primary-key-join) Can you please help with this