# mysql varying timestamp as primary key, join

Tags: mysql, sql

TABLE A as below:

```
SELECT value, 
       timestamp  
FROM   STATS_LABEL 
       RIGHT JOIN var_ref_table 
               ON var_ref_table.ref = STATS_LABEL.var_ref 
       AND value IS NOT NULL;
```

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| value                                                         | timestamp  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Ingested.between:[2019/08/26 12:30:00 to 2019/08/27 12:30:00] | 1566891281 |
| Ingested.between:[2019/08/27 12:30:00 to 2019/08/28 12:30:00] | 1566923678 |
| Ingested.between:[2019/08/27 12:30:00 to 2019/08/28 12:30:00] | 1566993041 |
| Ingested.between:[2019/08/28 12:30:00 to 2019/08/29 12:30:00] | 1567009019 |
| Ingested.between:[2019/08/29 12:30:00 to 2019/08/30 12:30:00] | 1567097659 |
| Ingested.between:[2019/08/30 12:30:00 to 2019/08/31 12:30:00] | 1567181049 |
| Ingested.between:[2019/08/31 12:30:00 to 2019/09/01 12:30:00] | 1567269570 |
| Ingested.between:[2019/09/01 12:30:00 to 2019/09/02 12:30:00] | 1567360255 |
| Ingested.between:[2019/09/02 12:30:00 to 2019/09/03 12:30:00] | 1567446656 |
| Ingested.between:[2019/09/03 12:30:00 to 2019/09/04 12:30:00] | 1567533054 |
| Ingested.between:[2019/09/04 12:30:00 to 2019/09/05 12:30:00] | 1567619455 |
| Ingested.between:[2019/09/05 12:30:00 to 2019/09/06 12:30:00] | 1567705855 |
| Ingested.between:[2019/09/06 12:30:00 to 2019/09/07 12:30:00] | 1567792256 |
| Ingested.between:[2019/09/06 12:30:00 to 2019/09/07 12:30:00] | 1567849462 |
| Ingested.between:[2019/09/07 12:30:00 to 2019/09/08 12:30:00] | 1567881861 |
| Ingested.between:[2019/09/08 12:30:00 to 2019/09/09 12:30:00] | 1567965018 |
| Ingested.between:[2019/09/09 12:30:00 to 2019/09/10 12:30:00] | 1568051420 |
| Ingested.between:[2019/09/10 12:30:00 to 2019/09/11 12:30:00] | 1568137822 |
| Ingested.between:[2019/09/11 12:30:00 to 2019/09/12 12:30:00] | 1568224218 |
| Ingested.between:[2019/09/12 12:30:00 to 2019/09/13 12:30:00] | 1568310619 |
| Ingested.between:[2019/09/12 12:30:00 to 2019/09/13 12:30:00] | 1568383994 |
| Ingested.between:[2019/09/13 12:30:00 to 2019/09/14 12:30:00] | 1568394793 |
| Ingested.between:[2019/09/14 12:30:00 to 2019/09/15 12:30:00] | 1568525418 |
| Ingested.between:[2019/09/15 12:30:00 to 2019/09/16 12:30:00] | 1568568608 |
| Ingested.between:[2019/09/16 12:30:00 to 2019/09/17 12:30:00] | 1568656264 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Table B as below:

```
SELECT value as stats, 
       var_ref_table.varname, 
       timestamp
FROM   APAC 
       RIGHT JOIN var_ref_table 
               ON var_ref_table.ref = APAC.var_ref 
WHERE  value >= 1566891281;
```

```
+--------+----------------------+-------------+
| STATS  |       VARNAME        | TIMESTAMP   |
+--------+----------------------+-------------+
| 395523 | %ccro-apac-stats.TOE |  1566891281 |
|     63 | %ccro-apac-stats.BRM |  1566891281 |
|     11 | %ccro-apac-stats.GAE |  1566891281 |
|     10 | %ccro-apac-stats.CAI |  1566891281 |
|    117 | %ccro-apac-stats.WCM |  1566891281 |
|    253 | %ccro-apac-stats.RM  |  1566891281 |
|      5 | %ccro-apac-stats.ISM |  1566891281 |
|     30 | %ccro-apac-stats.EMC |  1566891281 |
| 116535 | %ccro-apac-stats.TOE |  1566923678 |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.BRM |  1566923678 |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.GAE |  1566923678 |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.CAI |  1566923678 |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.WCM |  1566923678 |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.RM  |  1566923678 |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.ISM |  1566923678 |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.EMC |  1566923678 |
| 179959 | %ccro-apac-stats.TOE |  1566924951 |
| 240816 | %ccro-apac-stats.TOE |  1566936000 |
|     53 | %ccro-apac-stats.BRM |  1566946801 |
|      8 | %ccro-apac-stats.GAE |  1566946801 |
|     26 | %ccro-apac-stats.CAI |  1566946801 |
|     15 | %ccro-apac-stats.EMC |  1566946801 |
| 240816 | %ccro-apac-stats.TOE |  1566993041 |
|     53 | %ccro-apac-stats.BRM |  1566993041 |
|      8 | %ccro-apac-stats.GAE |  1566993041 |
|     26 | %ccro-apac-stats.CAI |  1566993041 |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.WCM |  1566993041 |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.RM  |  1566993041 |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.ISM |  1566993041 |
|     15 | %ccro-apac-stats.EMC |  1566993041 |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.TOE |  1567009019 |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.BRM |  1567009019 |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.GAE |  1567009019 |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.CAI |  1567009019 |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.EMC |  1567009019 |
|  58176 | %ccro-apac-stats.TOE |  1567019763 |
|     26 | %ccro-apac-stats.BRM |  1567036237 |
|     14 | %ccro-apac-stats.CAI |  1567036237 |
|      2 | %ccro-apac-stats.ISM |  1567036237 |
|      7 | %ccro-apac-stats.EMC |  1567036237 |
| 119405 | %ccro-apac-stats.TOE |  1567097659 |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.BRM |  1567097659 |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.CAI |  1567097659 |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.ISM |  1567097659 |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.EMC |  1567097659 |
| 133229 | %ccro-apac-stats.TOE |  1567114700 |
| 250163 | %ccro-apac-stats.TOE |  1567122643 |
|     45 | %ccro-apac-stats.BRM |  1567122643 |
|      7 | %ccro-apac-stats.GAE |  1567122643 |
|      8 | %ccro-apac-stats.CAI |  1567122643 |
+--------+----------------------+-------------+
```

I want something like below.

```
+--------+----------------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| STATS  |       VARNAME        | TIMESTAMP  |                             VALUE                              |
+--------+----------------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 395523 | %ccro-apac-stats.TOE | 1566891281 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/26 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/27 12:30:00]  |
|     63 | %ccro-apac-stats.BRM | 1566891281 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/26 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/27 12:30:00]  |
|     11 | %ccro-apac-stats.GAE | 1566891281 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/26 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/27 12:30:00]  |
|     10 | %ccro-apac-stats.CAI | 1566891281 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/26 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/27 12:30:00]  |
|    117 | %ccro-apac-stats.WCM | 1566891281 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/26 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/27 12:30:00]  |
|    253 | %ccro-apac-stats.RM  | 1566891281 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/26 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/27 12:30:00]  |
|      5 | %ccro-apac-stats.ISM | 1566891281 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/26 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/27 12:30:00]  |
|     30 | %ccro-apac-stats.EMC | 1566891281 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/26 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/27 12:30:00]  |
| 116535 | %ccro-apac-stats.TOE | 1566923678 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/27 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/28 12:30:00]  |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.BRM | 1566923678 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/27 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/28 12:30:00]  |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.GAE | 1566923678 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/27 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/28 12:30:00]  |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.CAI | 1566923678 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/27 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/28 12:30:00]  |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.WCM | 1566923678 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/27 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/28 12:30:00]  |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.RM  | 1566923678 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/27 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/28 12:30:00]  |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.ISM | 1566923678 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/27 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/28 12:30:00]  |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.EMC | 1566923678 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/27 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/28 12:30:00]  |
| 179959 | %ccro-apac-stats.TOE | 1566924951 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/27 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/28 12:30:00]  |
| 240816 | %ccro-apac-stats.TOE | 1566936000 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/27 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/28 12:30:00]  |
|     53 | %ccro-apac-stats.BRM | 1566946801 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/27 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/28 12:30:00]  |
|      8 | %ccro-apac-stats.GAE | 1566946801 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/27 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/28 12:30:00]  |
|     26 | %ccro-apac-stats.CAI | 1566946801 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/27 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/28 12:30:00]  |
|     15 | %ccro-apac-stats.EMC | 1566946801 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/27 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/28 12:30:00]  |
| 240816 | %ccro-apac-stats.TOE | 1566993041 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/27 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/28 12:30:00]  |
|     53 | %ccro-apac-stats.BRM | 1566993041 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/27 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/28 12:30:00]  |
|      8 | %ccro-apac-stats.GAE | 1566993041 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/27 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/28 12:30:00]  |
|     26 | %ccro-apac-stats.CAI | 1566993041 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/27 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/28 12:30:00]  |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.WCM | 1566993041 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/27 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/28 12:30:00]  |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.RM  | 1566993041 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/27 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/28 12:30:00]  |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.ISM | 1566993041 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/27 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/28 12:30:00]  |
|     15 | %ccro-apac-stats.EMC | 1566993041 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/27 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/28 12:30:00]  |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.TOE | 1567009019 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/28 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/29 12:30:00]  |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.BRM | 1567009019 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/28 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/29 12:30:00]  |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.GAE | 1567009019 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/28 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/29 12:30:00]  |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.CAI | 1567009019 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/28 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/29 12:30:00]  |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.EMC | 1567009019 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/28 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/29 12:30:00]  |
|  58176 | %ccro-apac-stats.TOE | 1567019763 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/28 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/29 12:30:00]  |
|     26 | %ccro-apac-stats.BRM | 1567036237 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/28 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/29 12:30:00]  |
|     14 | %ccro-apac-stats.CAI | 1567036237 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/28 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/29 12:30:00]  |
|      2 | %ccro-apac-stats.ISM | 1567036237 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/28 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/29 12:30:00]  |
|      7 | %ccro-apac-stats.EMC | 1567036237 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/28 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/29 12:30:00]  |
| 119405 | %ccro-apac-stats.TOE | 1567097659 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/29 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/30 12:30:00]  |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.BRM | 1567097659 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/29 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/30 12:30:00]  |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.CAI | 1567097659 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/29 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/30 12:30:00]  |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.ISM | 1567097659 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/29 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/30 12:30:00]  |
|      0 | %ccro-apac-stats.EMC | 1567097659 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/29 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/30 12:30:00]  |
| 133229 | %ccro-apac-stats.TOE | 1567114700 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/29 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/30 12:30:00]  |
| 250163 | %ccro-apac-stats.TOE | 1567122643 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/29 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/30 12:30:00]  |
|     45 | %ccro-apac-stats.BRM | 1567122643 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/29 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/30 12:30:00]  |
|      7 | %ccro-apac-stats.GAE | 1567122643 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/29 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/30 12:30:00]  |
|      8 | %ccro-apac-stats.CAI | 1567122643 | Ingested.between:[2019/08/29 12:30:00 TO 2019/08/30 12:30:00]  |
+--------+----------------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I need to get the query printed for all rows in TABLE B whose timestamp < timestamp of TABLE A, and when it changes, the new set of values should be printed

Comment: Which table does the column value belong to?

Comment: Added the desc of the 3 tables involved

Comment: It's good programming practice to always qualify _all_ column names, at least when there are more than one table involved. E.g. `APAC.var_ref` instead of just `var_ref`.

Comment: Sure, I am unable to add the desc here. So, the value is a common column in both APAC & STATS_LABEL tables....structure of both are same.....both tables contains 4 columns

timestamp, value, var_ref & node_ref

Comment: @jarlh any help here will be greatly appreciated please